2 factor authenticaton issue. I have never used or set up 2 factor authenticator and now I am not able to log in
I just registered in Ubuntu One, I do not remember having account before but now when I log in it is asking me for 2 factor authenticator. I never had it and never used it( seems that the site know it because there is a message above sayng that I never used my 2 factor authentication, but now I cannot log in. Is there any support email where I can sent the description of the issue and they sent me a linck to set up this 2 factor authenticator?
